# stack overflow servlet tutorial error

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
 $ java -version java version "1.6.0_45" Java(TM) SE Runtime
 Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-10M4406) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
 Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat version: 7.0.40

I'm following the beginning servlet/jsp tutorial here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

and I am getting this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri:
>   http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions cannot be resolved in either
>   web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Which looks like it's coming from the .jsp file which begins with this line:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

I compiled my servlet like this:

```
~/java_programs/modernServlet$ javac -cp /Library/Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar -d classes src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java
```

And then I copied that file to the same directory structure under WEB-INF classes in the Tomcat directory.  Is there some other jar file I should be including in the classpath?

====

Okay, I downloaded and copied the jstl jar to Tomcat's lib directory, and and now I get all kinds of compile errors:

```
$ javac -cp "/Library/Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar;/Library/Tomcat/lib/jstl-1.2.jar" -d classes src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:7: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:8: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                               ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:9: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                         ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:10: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                         ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:11: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
                         ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
                                  ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol: class WebServlet
@WebServlet("/hello")
 ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                         ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                                     ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                                                                          ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                          ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                                      ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class com.example.controller.HelloServlet
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                                                                                           ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:16: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
src/com/example/controller/HelloServlet.java:22: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
15 errors
```

Comment: WTF? Why do we have an *entire tutorial* in the *tag wiki*? (Also the use of "post-process" and "preprocess" in that tag wiki is ... very strange).

Comment: You may be missing the jstl jar from the classpath.

Comment: @Lee Meador, Thanks for the response.  I don't see a jstl jar in Tomcats lib directory.

Comment: No need to add jstl library in classpath while compiling servlet. It should be placed inside your app. lib folder.

Comment: @laksys, App lib folder or Tomcat lib folder?  If App lib folder, where in the directory structure does the lib folder go?

Comment: @Joachim: please bring to meta if the wiki bothers you. A lot of starters have found it tremendously helpful.

Comment: @BalusC: "bothers me" is much to strong. I was merely surprised.

Comment: I put the jstl-1.2.jar in my app's WEB-INF/lib directory, and I get the same error that I originally got.

Comment: @Joachim: it's maybe the language; I wouldn't use "WTF" in a statement of surprise. 7stud: see my answer, you don't need it in the compiletime classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a compilation error. This is a runtime error.

You just need to drop JSTL in `/WEB-INF/lib` as instructed in [JSTL tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (and indirectly also the [JSP tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)).

You don't need to specify it in the compiletime classpath. It's namely a runtime error, not a compilation error. You successfully compiled the servlet, right?

Your compilation error while attempting to compile with JSTL in the classpath is caused because you're using Windows-specific path separator `;` in the classpath while you're using an Unix based OS which expects `:` as path separator. But after all, you don't need JSTL in compiletime classpath.

Comment: I put the jstl-1.2.jar in my app's WEB-INF/lib directory, and I get the same error that I originally got.

Comment: Perhaps you've copied multiple different versioned JSTL JAR files spreading throughout the runtime classpath in an attempt to solve this problem. This is not right. This problem can also be caused by having e.g. JSTL 1.0 in JRE/lib or Tomcat/common having precedence over webapp's libs. I suggest to undo all attempts to fix this particular problem and make sure that you haven't touched the default JRE/JRK and Tomcat configuration.

Comment: No.  There's one jar file, which I first moved to Tomcat's lib directory, and then I moved it from that directory to my app's lib directory.  And there is no Tomcat/common directory.

Comment: How are you deploying? Did you rebuild the WAR and clean/restart Tomcat?

Comment: Have you read that tutorial?  There is no deploying.  This is local development running Tomcat standalone.   I'm not even using Eclipse.  The word "WAR" doesn't appear anywhere in the tutorial.  I have not restarted Tomcat.  I'll try that.  Well, well, well...that worked.  Why?

Comment: I wrote that tutorial. It clearly states "deploy the webapp". The deployment step itself is not elaborated in detail because it depends on environment being used and it's assumed to be already understood by the user as it's part of basic knowledge (like the compiling step). The redeploy of WAR (if any) and restart is mandatory because JARs are read only once during startup and kept in memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31535/discussion-between-7stud-and-balusc)

Comment: Okay, I see it now.  I don't know why you would expect that a beginner doing a hello world servlet/jsp app would have any idea what "deploy the web app" means.  I certainly don't.

Comment: It's covered in Tomcat and Java EE tutorials (which in turn do not flesh out the use of servlets as in the tag wiki page).

Comment: 1)In the tutorial, how come you named the jsp file hello.jsp and you also mapped a url named /hello to the servlet? That's a tad confusing. 2)Are files in WEB-INF publicly accessible?

Comment: 1) `/hello.jsp` JSP is the view and `/hello` servlet is the associated controller. You can name them whatever you want, but it'd make sense if you can easily relate them to each other in some way. 2) No. You don't want to leak away potentially sensitive information in among others `web.xml` and friends.

Comment: 2) Then how are you able to access hello.jsp?  3) How do you serve up a static html file?

Comment: 2) Using servlet as shown in tutorial. 3) "The usual way". Just put file in public webcontent (but not inside `/WEB-INF`) and specify its filename in URL. The same applies to other static resources like CSS/JS/images.

Comment: 2)Ah, I see.  The _servlet_ is sending back the jsp page, and the jsp page requests the servlet again when the user hits Submit.  I thought the initial request was asking for a publicly accessible jsp page, and then the jsp page was sending a request to the servlet when the user hit submit. See how naming the jsp file and servlet url the same can lead to confusion?3) webcontent?  I assume that is a directory, which I don't know about.  I can't seem to find a recent tutorial that specifies the proper directory structure.

Comment: 2) I already explained that in the tutorial text. Perhaps you need to take a step back and learn basic HTTP (and HTML) before servlets. 3) it's just a generic term, not a fixed folder name. The webcontent is the parent folder of `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`). It's mentioned in standard Java EE tutorial.

Comment: "I wrote that tutorial. It clearly states 'deploy the webapp'".  For anyone else who doesn't understand what "deployment" means, it simply means put your servlet files/jsp's/etc in the correct directories in Tomcat and restart Tomcat.  Tomcat doesn't see changes that you make to your servlet unless you restart it.

Comment: ...And a WAR file is just a snapshot of your whole development directory structure.  After taking a snapshot of your development structure, all you have to do is move one file, the WAR file, to Tomcat and drop it into Tomcat/webapps. Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the JSTL jar to the Tomcat lib folder.

You can download it by going here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Click the "download" button and just copy that file into Tomcat's lib folder.

New errors mean that servlet-api.jar is missing from the classpath.

Comment: I tried that but now I get a lot of compile errors, which I added to my post.